# Share `Play Store` Link in `DrawerNavigator` Menu via react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**I have 3 Screen Items in my DrawerNavigator Menu.**

How to add a Share `Play Store` Link in DrawerNavigator Menu under Item "3"?
I mean That is not a real page, Just That is a Aplication Share Link with Icon, When someone Clicks that Share area will opens.

```
const Router = DrawerNavigator(
    {  
        Home: { screen: MainScreen },
        New: { screen: News },
        Photo: { screen: Photos },
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom `contentComponent` option https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer#Providing-a-custom-contentComponent for the DrawerNavigator. Something like this

```
    const Router = DrawerNavigator(
      {  
         Home: { screen: MainScreen },
         New: { screen: News },
         Photo: { screen: Photos },
     },
     {
     contentComponent: props => {
        return (
          <ScrollView>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => {
                Share.share({
                  message: PLAY_STORE_URL
                });
              }}>
                <Text>
                  Share
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </ScrollView>
        );
      }
   )
```